# MongoDB Select inside Update query

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb

I am using a MongoDB database as a temp table for some import operations. I want to perform a stored procedure on the data before it is permanently persisted into our SQL database. This relies on using a map inside Mongo to replace 4 characters from a int field.

I am not quite sure how to do this in Mongo, but if these tables were inside SQL the query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE data SET number = 
IF LEN(number) >= 4 BEGIN
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(number, 1, (LEN(number)-4)), (SELECT replacement FROM mapping WHERE original=SUBSTRING(number, (LEN(number)-4), 4))
END ELSE number
```

Meaning, if the number is 4 digits or more, replace the last 4 digits with the replacement in the mapping table, else do nothing.

Can anyone help me translate this into a MongoDB query(I am using C# in case that is relevant)? I am really lost right now.

Comment: I think, you would write `LEN(number) - 4` instead of `LEN(number - 4)` inside the query.

Comment: And the second `SUBSTRING` call doesn't take any string parameter.

Comment: Yup, you are right, fixed those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this work within one `update` query, but you can use JavaScript function for updating necessary items:

```
db.data.find().forEach(function (item) {
    var numberLength = item.number.length;
    if (numberLength >= 4) {
        var part1 = item.number.substring(0, numberLength - 4);
        var part2 = item.number.substring(numberLength - 4);

        var mapping = db.mapping.findOne({ original: part2 });

        item.number = part1 + (!!mapping ? mapping.replacement : "");
        db.data.save(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid loading all the data into memory because of the size of data I am running this procedure on. (Milions at a time)

Perhaps another solution... Could I add two properties to each record, make one the original 4 digits with one query, make the other the 4 replacement digits from mapping with another and then update the number in a third query? Just trying to keep all the processing in Mongo and as streamlined as possible.

Nevermind, I guess that wouldn't work because I still need to select the mapping digits within an update query... Damn.

Comment: After having a talk with my architect we determined that it wasn't that big of a deal to load the data into memory so I ended up doing something similar to you except with our own already defined methods. However, this would have worked if we didn't have those set up. Thanks!